# Problem with sharepoint 2010 conditional formatting (setting color to text in rows)

Tags: sharepoint, formatting, moss, conditional-statements

i'm tring to set conditional formatting for sharepoint list (2010).
I have a list with a few columns. One of them have 2 values available. 1 or 0.
if 1 then the text in all rows in my list must get color RED.
if 0 then do nothing.
in design mode in sharepoint designer i can see the color red, but the browser doesnt show it at all!
is this a bug of sharepoint? does the code created is not vaild code for browsers?

this is the condition code:

```
    <xsl:if test="$thisNode/@findWord = '1'" 
ddwrt:cf_explicit="1" 
xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime">
     color: #FF0000; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;   
      text-decoration: underline;
</xsl:if>
```

thanks.
gadym.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add findword column in viewfields which you can find under view tag

```
    <FieldRef  Name ="findWord" />
```

Working Syntax is provided below for choice column type taking 1 and 0 as input

```
<xsl:variable name="titlevalue" select="$thisNode/@Title"/>
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="$titlevalue=''">
        <xsl:value-of select="'(no title)'"/>
      </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
           <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="$HasTitleField">
            <span>
       <xsl:attribute name="style">
        <xsl:if test="normalize-space($thisNode/@findWord) = '1'" ddwrt:cf_explicit="1">font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #FF0000; text-decoration: underline; font-weight: bold; background-color: #BDDFD9;</xsl:if>
       </xsl:attribute>
       <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$titlevalue" />
       </span></xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$titlevalue" />
          </xsl:otherwise>
           </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
```